# An element of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

An element $A$ of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is called an *elliptic element* if $|\text{tr}(A)|<2$.

> Find the relationship between an elliptic element of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and rotation.

As $|\text{tr}(A)|<2$ the characteristic equation of $A$ does not have real roots, so it has no real eigenvalue. But I am unable to go ahead.

Answer (score 4):

Let $g$ be your elliptic element. Since the eigenvalues are complex conjugate, $g$ will have an eigenvector $\binom z1\in\Bbb C^2$ with the imaginary part of $z$ positive.

It can be shown that you can always find some $h\in{\rm SL}_2(\Bbb R)$ such that $h\binom i1=c\binom z1$ for some $c\in\Bbb R$.

Thus $h^{-1}gh$ will have $\binom i1$ as eigenvector.

The final step is to show that the elements of ${\rm SL}_2(\Bbb R)$ having $\binom i1$ as an eigenvector are precisely the elements in the subgroup ${\rm SO}_2(\Bbb R)$, i.e. the rotations.

I leave the details as an exercise.

Comment: That can be easily obtained just writing it down what it means.

Comment: Suppose that $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\c & d\end{array}\right)\binom i1=\lambda\binom i1$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb C$. Then $\frac{ai+b}{ci+d}=\frac{\lambda i}\lambda=i$. This yelds $a=d$ and $b=-c$. Combining this with $ad-bc=1$ you get $a^2+b^2=1$ so that $a=\cos t$, $b=\sin t$ for some $t\in \Bbb R$. But then your original matrix is rotation by $t$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a second proof. Let $\theta\in\Bbb R\setminus\pi\Bbb Z$ be such that $\mathrm{Tr}(A)=2\cos(\theta)$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ equals $\chi_A(X)=X^2-\mathrm{Tr}(A)X+\det(A)=(X-e^{i\theta})(X-e^{-i\theta})=\chi_{R_{\theta}}(X)$ where
$$
R_{\theta}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since $\theta\notin\pi\Bbb Z$, $e^{i\theta}\neq e^{-i\theta}$ and $A$ and $R_{\theta}$ are diagonalzable (over $\Bbb C$) and conjugate (as complex matrices) to
$$\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\theta}&0\\0&e^{-i\theta}
\end{pmatrix}$$
We conclude by invoking the general fact that two real matrices that are conjugate as complex matrices are conjugate as real matrices.

Comment: how is this very last fact obvious? (I asked this as a question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972304/real-vs-complex-conjugate)