# If two real matrices are conjugated over $\mathbb{C}$, are they then also conjugated over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As in the title:

If two real (square) matrices are conjugated over $\mathbb{C}$, are they then also conjugated over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @MorganRodgers: I think what's meant by "conjugated over a field $k$" here is "conjugate(d) by conjugation with a matrix with entries in $k$".

Comment: @MorganRodgers: I believe the two terms are essential synonymous; from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity, it seems that as far as there's any difference between them, "conjugate" is the more appropriate one.

Comment: [This is a related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57242/similar-matrices-and-field-extensions)

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/972304/11619) for an argument specific to $\Bbb{C}/\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers It just depends on the author; both terms are in fairly common general use.  Yes, "conjugate" is more general group theory and "similar" is more matrix-specific, but you terms used interchangeably even within these divisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is yes. For one, it suffices to note that any real matrix is similar to some matrix in [real Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices), and that any two similar real matrices share such a real Jordan form.

There may be a way to show this directly that doesn't use such powerful techniques, but this certainly works.

Comment: Reference: see for example Horn and Johnson's Matrix Analysis, Theorem 3.4.5.

Comment: Did you mean Theorem 3.4.1.5?

Comment: BTW  In the proof of 3.4.1.5, they refer to 1.3.28 and 1.3.29 - these two results make a shorter proof that completely answers my question, without Jordan normal forms. Thank you very much for that reference!

Comment: Oh, well you're welcome; I  guess I missed that.